# Using special character for column alias - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I trying to alias a column with "a&b": 
eg:

```
SELECT numberofemployees "Employees (D&B)" from account;
```

or

```
SELECT numberofemployees as "Employees (D&B)" from account;
```

Every other character works fine except for the "&".
This query is prompting me to give a value for a variable.
I am using it in PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: SELECT numberofemployees as [Employees (D&B)] from account;

Comment: Use `SET DEFINE OFF`, and it will work for that particular session.

Comment: If you are running in PLSQL Developer's SQL Window, use double ampersand (&&), it will print only once without any prompt.